# asp.net Identity: CreateAsync cannot access a disposed object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

I am trying to create a user from a blazer component.

here is my injection:
`@inject UserManager<CustomUser> usrm`

And the implementation:

```
async Task<bool> CreateLoginUser()
    {
        var user = new CustomUser { UserName = SelectedPerson.Email, Email = SelectedPerson.Email };
        var result = await usrm.CreateAsync(user, UserPassword);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User Created");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

When I call this method this I get:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
      Object name: 'UserManager`1'.
```

I have looked at almost every answer on Stackoverflow related to this error, I have checked that I don't have another instance of usermanager. It is obviously async and a Task not a void. I've also tried the classic clean project and restart VS but made no change. I even tried ChatGPT. My backup plan is to try create the users manually but I don't understand why this isn't working. When the code crashes it blames line 150 which is `var result = await usrm.CreateAsync(user, UserPassword);` This is a Blazor Server app.

Comment: Check if you dispose the identity database context somewhere else. This will also cause the error. Such as "using(context..) " will also dispose.

Comment: How is `CreateLoginUser` called?

Answer (score 0):

In a Blazor Server app, the dependency injection system manages the lifetime of services, and they are scoped to the lifetime of the request.

Here are a few things to check and try:

1. **Scoped Lifetime**: Ensure that your UserManager is
   registered as a scoped service in your dependency injection setup.
   In a Blazor Server app, you typically register services in the
   Startup.cs file.

   ```
   services.AddDefaultIdentity<CustomUser>()
       .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
   ```
2. **DbContext:** If you are using Entity Framework and a DbContext for
   CustomUser, ensure that it is also scoped correctly.

   ```
   services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
   options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
   ```

if you're still facing the issue,  ensure that your NuGet packages, especially those related to Identity and ASP.NET Core, are up to date.